# Как скомбинировать IN и LIKE? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы:
`reports.students s`
`initki.visit v`

Связь :
`s.session = v.session_id || '%'`
(например : 1234 = 1234-qwerty)

Нужно вытащить сеансы c таблицы `v`, которые совпадают с сеансами в таблице `s` в указанном диапазоне

Я думал написать, как то так (смотреть ниже), но насколько я понимаю `IN` и `LIKE` использовать вместе нельзя:

```
SELECT substring(session_id, 1, 13) 
FROM initki.visit v
WHERE v.session_id IN LIKE 
(SELECT pch.session||'%' 
FROM reports.students s
WHERE s.session BETWEEN 12418 AND 14447)
```

Если `IN` и `LIKE` можно скомбинировать, подскажите как, или как еще можно получить нужные сеансы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать LIKE ANY:

```
SELECT substring(session_id, 1, 13) 
  FROM initki.visit v
 WHERE v.session_id LIKE ANY
      (SELECT pch.session||'%' 
         FROM reports.students s
        WHERE s.session BETWEEN 12418 AND 14447)
```

Или заменить подзапрос на обычную склейку (Если это не приведет к изменению количества записей):

```
SELECT substring(v.session_id, 1, 13) 
  FROM initki.visit v
  JOIN reports.students s
    ON v.session_id LIKE s.session||'%'
 WHERE s.session BETWEEN 12418 AND 14447
```

Comment: `LIKE ANY` помог! Какая разница между `LIKE ANY` и `LIKE ALL`?

Comment: @Giovanni Огромная. LIKE ALL выберет только такие записи основной таблицы для которых like сработает на всех масках подзапроса. Т.е. `'abc' like all(select '%a%' union select '%D%')` не сработает т.к. подошла только одна маска. ANY же достаточно одного совпадения